# Determining a region in the plane

Tags: calculus

I would like to exactly know what does the following sentence mean.

"Let S be the region bounded by $y=x^2-1$ $y=0$ and $x=2$".

Me, I think the wanted region lies in the upper half plane $y>0$. But a professor in our department argues that the region between $y=0$ and $y=x^2-1$  is also  contained in our region.

thanks

P.S. The question originally is the area of the region (Calculus)

Comment: If the region is bounded and not unbounded on any side, it will lie above the x-axis.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to graph the three given functions, it seems that it would only make sense that the region S exists as $ \int_{1}^{2} (x^2-1) dx $, where the region starts at the intersection of $ y = x^{2} - 1 $ and $ y = 0 $ (1, 0), and ends at the intersection of $ y = x^{2} - 1 $ and $ x = 2 $ (2, 3). It couldn't exist elsewhere because it is bounded by the three functions, so the three functions must actively bind it, as in the case of the shaded region (S) in the image below.

**EDIT**

After looking at it a little more, a region from $ x = 2 $ to $ x = \infty $ is technically bounded by the three functions, but said region would be infinitely large.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There really is no clear interpretation of the region $S$. We only know that it is bounded by those three lines. It could even lie to the right of the line $x = 2$, below $y = x^2 - 1$ and above $y = 0$.

[image]